# Why does synchronization not work in the second code?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, runnable

Synchronization works correctly in this code:

```
    class PrintNumbers {
        synchronized public void display() {
            System.out.println("in display");
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                System.out.println("Thread name : "+ Thread.currentThread().getName() + " i= " + i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("out of display");
        }
    }

    class MyThread implements Runnable {
        Thread t;
        PrintNumbers printNumbers;

        MyThread(PrintNumbers printNumbers, String s) {
            this.printNumbers = printNumbers;
            t = new Thread(this,s);
            t.start();
        }

        public void run() {
            printNumbers.display();
        }
    }

    class SyncExample {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            PrintNumbers printNumbers = new PrintNumbers();

            new MyThread(printNumbers, "My Thread 1");
            new MyThread(printNumbers, "My Thread 2");
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
in display  
Thread name : My Thread 1 i= 0  
Thread name : My Thread 1 i= 1  
Thread name : My Thread 1 i= 2  
out of display
in display  
Thread name : My Thread 2 i= 0  
Thread name : My Thread 2 i= 1  
Thread name : My Thread 2 i= 2  
out of display
```

but not in this code:

```
    class PrintNumbers {
        synchronized public void display() {
            System.out.println("in display");
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                System.out.println("Thread name : "+ Thread.currentThread().getName() + " i= " + i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("out of display");
        }
    }

    class MyThread implements Runnable {
        Thread t;
        PrintNumbers printNumbers;

        MyThread(String s) {
            this.printNumbers = new PrintNumbers();
            t = new Thread(this,s);
            t.start();
        }

        public void run() {
            printNumbers.display();
        }
    }

    class SyncExample {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new MyThread("My Thread 1");
            new MyThread("My Thread 2");
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
in display  
Thread name : My Thread 1 i= 0  
in display  
Thread name : My Thread 2 i= 0  
Thread name : My Thread 1 i= 1  
Thread name : My Thread 2 i= 1  
Thread name : My Thread 2 i= 2  
Thread name : My Thread 1 i= 2  
out of display  
out of display
```

I cannot understand what difference wrt Synchronization does it make to initialize PrintNumbers in the Runnable MyThread and in the SyncExample class. Please explain.

Comment: non-static synchronized methods synchronize on `this`.

Comment: 2nd you need the `display` method static , they are locking 2 objects .

Comment: You are using difference object of PrintNumbers and lock is at object level. That's why you are getting different output.

Comment: "[When a thread invokes a synchronized method, it automatically acquires the intrinsic lock for that method's object \[...\]. You might wonder what happens when a static synchronized method is invoked, since a static method is associated with a class, not an object. In this case, the thread acquires the intrinsic lock for the Class object associated with the class. Thus access to class's static fields is controlled by a lock that's distinct from the lock for any instance of the class.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)"

Comment: Synchronization works on locking on object's monitor, and each object has its own monitor. If you create two PrintNumbers objects then you have two separate monitors so locking on one of them doesn't prevent other thread from locking on another (the one which it has access to).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I cannot understand what difference wrt Synchronization does it make to initialize PrintNumbers in the Runnable MyThread and in the SyncExample class.

It doesn't. What *does* matter is that in your first example, you have only **one** `PrintNumbers` instance which both threads share. But in your second example, you have two separate `PrintNumbers` instances, one for each thread.

Since `PrintNumbers#display` synchronizes on the instance (`synchronized` instance methods synchronize on `this`), it only synchronizes within the instance, not across multiple instances.

When both threads share an instance, the two calls to `display` are serialized. But when the threads each have their own instance, the two calls to `display` are on separate instances, and thus there is no serialization of the calls, they can overlap.

Answer (score 4):

Because in the second code each thread has its own `PrintNumbers` object so they work in parallel. In the first one they share the single `PrintNumbers` object and work with it in synchronized way.

PS.
Remember that `synchronized` for non-static methods makes synchronization on object (for static methods on class).

Answer (score 3):

It is working in both cases as it should. The difference is that in the first case you have a single object that is synchronized. In to second one you have two. They both are called only once so they are synchronized perfectly.

`synchronized` doesn't work between objects, only within one.